# Todo list using Recycler View Class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a simple Todo list app using edit text and add button. the text that I type is not added into the list by clicking the add button. is there a problem with the way i am using function notifyDataSetCahnged(). please tell the right way to implement it.

code for main code :

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
package com.example.todolist3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnAdd;
    private EditText etAdd;
    private RecyclerView rvText;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ToDoListRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        etAdd = findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
        rvText = findViewById(R.id.rvText);
        rvText.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Your text is entered here");
        adapter = new ToDoListRecyclerAdapter(list);
        rvText.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = etAdd.getText().toString();
                addText(text);
            }
        });
    }
    private void addText(String text){
      list.add(text);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

code for adapter :

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
package com.example.todolist3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToDoListRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoListRecyclerAdapter.ToDoListViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<String> list;
        public ToDoListRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> list){
            this.list=list;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ToDoListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View itemView=li.inflate(R.layout.todo_list_card,parent,false);
            return new ToDoListViewHolder(itemView)  ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToDoListViewHolder holder, int position) {
            String TodoList=list.get(position);
            holder.tvText.setText(TodoList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        class ToDoListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tvText;


            public ToDoListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
            }
        }
}
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: Do you see any items in your `RecyclerView` ? Could you provide your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the items to the `list` not to the `adapter` so it doesn't make effect make this function in adapter

```
 public void setData(String note){
 list.add(note);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

and call it from your add button clicklistener in `activity`